# 15 minute regimen for bulky arms

Tags: training, arms, mass

What exercises would you recommend to be done in under 15 minutes for bulky arms. I have tried some weight exercises in the past, but they failed to show results because of lack of follow through.

thanks!

Comment: back squats below parallel

Comment: 15 minutes just isn't enough. Big arms don't come for free. I spend 45-60 minutes on my arm routine 2-3 times per week and i started seeing results right away.

Comment: @EricKaufman How does back squats build arms?

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't get bulky arms in only 15 minutes of lifting, I would recommend at least 25-45 minutes twice a week if you want bulky arms.

Some good exercises for mass are:
1) 4 sets of 6-8 heavy barbell curls
2) 3 sets of 10-12 hammer dumbbell curls
3) 3 sets of 10-12 seated alternating dumbbell curls

It's import to "squeeze" the muscle at the top of the movement, and come back down slowly. Most of your growing and muscle fiber tearing happens on the negative of the rep.

Comment: Hammer curls are a forearm exercise. The biceps do not get sufficient work to build mass

Comment: Hammer curls work the long head of the bicep which help with the peak. It's important to work both heads for full development